# DocuSign redirect URL length limit

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to add oAuth flow to my webpage for DocuSign services and I found out that I can't configure integration app redirect URI that is longer than 100 symbols. Is it possible to bypass this limitation? Also I didn't find any official mentioning of this kind of limit. Is it specified somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall seeing max length of **redirect_uri** documented anywhere, but given that you can specify it via the DocuSign Web UI ("*The redirect URI must exactly match one of those pre-registered for the integrator key [via the web UI].*"), it's not surprising that there would be a max length imposed.

This other post discusses the max length of the **returnUrl** parameter in the `POST Recipient View` request -- which I realize different than the parameter you're asking about (**return_uri** in oAuth) -- but similar in concept: [DocuSign embedded signing returnUrl length limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158966/docusign-embedded-signing-returnurl-length-limit)  The answer suggests one possible work-around, which might be feasible in your scenario as well.